# What does multitier means in weblogic server JNDI Lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, initial-context

I was checking `InitialContext` object and properties that are need for JNDI lookup. One of the property which is required for InitialContext is `INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` for environment, for weblogic server its value is `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory`.

In the [documentation of weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs/weblogic/jndi/WLInitialContextFactory.html) it is said:

> weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory can also be used to create a ***multitier connection*** to another naming service through a WebLogic Server.

I did not understand the meaning of multitier connection. Can someone elaborate what exactly it means?

Answer (score 1):

Two-tier connections are when the client loads the connection driver into the same JVM and that driver communicates directly with the resource.

Multitier connections are when WebLogic loads a driver into its JVM. The client communicates with WebLogic. WebLogic communicates with the resource. (There could be additional steps inbetween.)

To use a database connection as an example, this is useful because your client doesn't need to have the native libraries for the database and you can allow WebLogic to manage particulars like connection pooling, keep alive, and stale connection disposal, or load balancing and failover.

It also allows you to configure details such as the remote machine name, user name, and password in WebLogic while your code only needs to know the JNDI name.

This should be saying that WebLogic supports remote naming services for you in a way that's similar to how you might set up a JNDI name for a JDBC connection, message queue/JMS, or other remote service.